# How to add relation data

Tags: go

I start to learn Golang with sample project from https://github.com/dejavuzhou/felix

My first project already runnning well. But I want some custom output. I mean I want to get relation data **Has Many** when I get order data, but I fail.

Start with my simple case, I have 2 tables (**order** and **detail_order**). One order has one or more detail_order.

My handler_order.go

```
    package handlers

    import (
        "github.com/berthojoris/ginbro/models"
        "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    )

    func init() {
        groupApi.GET("order", orderAll)
        groupApi.GET("order/:id", orderOne)
        groupApi.POST("order", orderCreate)
        groupApi.PATCH("order", orderUpdate)
        groupApi.DELETE("order/:id", orderDelete)
    }

    //All
    func orderAll(c *gin.Context) {
        mdl := models.Order{}
        query := &models.PaginationQuery{}
        err := c.ShouldBindQuery(query)
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        list, total, err := mdl.All(query)
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        jsonPagination(c, list, total, query)
    }

    //One
    func orderOne(c *gin.Context) {
        var mdl models.Order
        id, err := parseParamID(c)
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        mdl.Id = id
        data, err := mdl.One()
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        jsonData(c, data)
    }

    //Create
    func orderCreate(c *gin.Context) {
        var mdl models.Order
        err := c.ShouldBind(&mdl)
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        err = mdl.Create()
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        jsonData(c, mdl)
    }

    //Update
    func orderUpdate(c *gin.Context) {
        var mdl models.Order
        err := c.ShouldBind(&mdl)
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        err = mdl.Update()
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        jsonSuccess(c)
    }

    //Delete
    func orderDelete(c *gin.Context) {
        var mdl models.Order
        id, err := parseParamID(c)
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        mdl.Id = id
        err = mdl.Delete()
        if handleError(c, err) {
            return
        }
        jsonSuccess(c)
    }
```

My model_order.go

```
package models

import (
    "errors"
    "time"
)

var _ = time.Thursday

//Order
type Order struct {
    Id    uint    `gorm:"column:id" form:"id" json:"id" comment:"" sql:"int(10),PRI"`
    Total float64 `gorm:"column:total" form:"total" json:"total" comment:"" sql:"double"`
    OrderDetail []OrderDetail `gorm:"foreignkey:OrderID" json:"detail_order"`
}

//TableName
func (m *Order) TableName() string {
    return "order"
}

//One
func (m *Order) One() (one *Order, err error) {
    one = &Order{}
    err = crudOne(m, one)
    return
}

//All
func (m *Order) All(q *PaginationQuery) (list *[]Order, total uint, err error) {
    list = &[]Order{}
    total, err = crudAll(m, q, list)
    return
}

//Update
func (m *Order) Update() (err error) {
    where := Order{Id: m.Id}
    m.Id = 0

    return crudUpdate(m, where)
}

//Create
func (m *Order) Create() (err error) {
    m.Id = 0

    return mysqlDB.Create(m).Error
}

//Delete
func (m *Order) Delete() (err error) {
    if m.Id == 0 {
        return errors.New("resource must not be zero value")
    }
    return crudDelete(m)
}
```

My model_order_detail.go

```
package models

import (
    "errors"
    "time"
)

var _ = time.Thursday

//OrderDetail
type OrderDetail struct {
    Id        uint    `gorm:"column:id" form:"id" json:"id" comment:"" sql:"int(10),PRI"`
    OrderId   int     `gorm:"column:order_id" form:"order_id" json:"order_id" comment:"" sql:"int(10),MUL"`
    ItemId    int     `gorm:"column:item_id" form:"item_id" json:"item_id" comment:"" sql:"int(10)"`
    ItemName  string  `gorm:"column:item_name" form:"item_name" json:"item_name" comment:"" sql:"varchar(100)"`
    ItemPrice float64 `gorm:"column:item_price" form:"item_price" json:"item_price" comment:"" sql:"double"`
}

//TableName
func (m *OrderDetail) TableName() string {
    return "order_detail"
}

//One
func (m *OrderDetail) One() (one *OrderDetail, err error) {
    one = &OrderDetail{}
    err = crudOne(m, one)
    return
}

//All
func (m *OrderDetail) All(q *PaginationQuery) (list *[]OrderDetail, total uint, err error) {
    list = &[]OrderDetail{}
    total, err = crudAll(m, q, list)
    return
}

//Update
func (m *OrderDetail) Update() (err error) {
    where := OrderDetail{Id: m.Id}
    m.Id = 0

    return crudUpdate(m, where)
}

//Create
func (m *OrderDetail) Create() (err error) {
    m.Id = 0

    return mysqlDB.Create(m).Error
}

//Delete
func (m *OrderDetail) Delete() (err error) {
    if m.Id == 0 {
        return errors.New("resource must not be zero value")
    }
    return crudDelete(m)
}
```

And my db_helper.go

```
package models

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

//PaginationQuery gin handler query binding struct
type PaginationQuery struct {
    Where  string `form:"where"`
    Fields string `form:"fields"`
    Order  string `form:"order"`
    Offset uint   `form:"offset"`
    Limit  uint   `form:"limit"`
}

//String to string
func (pq *PaginationQuery) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("w=%v_f=%s_o=%s_of=%d_l=%d", pq.Where, pq.Fields, pq.Order, pq.Offset, pq.Limit)
}

func crudAll(m interface{}, q *PaginationQuery, list interface{}) (total uint, err error) {
    var tx *gorm.DB
    total, tx = getResourceCount(m, q)
    if q.Fields != "" {
        columns := strings.Split(q.Fields, ",")
        if len(columns) > 0 {
            tx = tx.Select(q.Fields)
        }
    }
    if q.Order != "" {
        tx = tx.Order(q.Order)
    }
    if q.Offset > 0 {
        tx = tx.Offset(q.Offset)
    }
    if q.Limit <= 0 {
        q.Limit = 15
    }
    err = tx.Limit(q.Limit).Find(list).Error
    return
}

func crudOne(m interface{}, one interface{}) (err error) {
    if mysqlDB.Where(m).First(one).RecordNotFound() {
        return errors.New("resource is not found")
    }
    return nil
}

func crudUpdate(m interface{}, where interface{}) (err error) {
    db := mysqlDB.Model(where).Updates(m)
    if err = db.Error; err != nil {
        return
    }
    if db.RowsAffected != 1 {
        return errors.New("id is invalid and resource is not found")
    }
    return nil
}

func crudDelete(m interface{}) (err error) {
    //WARNING When delete a record, you need to ensure it’s primary field has value, and GORM will use the primary key to delete the record, if primary field’s blank, GORM will delete all records for the model
    //primary key must be not zero value
    db := mysqlDB.Delete(m)
    if err = db.Error; err != nil {
        return
    }
    if db.RowsAffected != 1 {
        return errors.New("resource is not found to destroy")
    }
    return nil
}
func getResourceCount(m interface{}, q *PaginationQuery) (uint, *gorm.DB) {
    var tx = mysqlDB.Model(m)
    conditions := strings.Split(q.Where, ",")
    for _, val := range conditions {
        w := strings.SplitN(val, ":", 2)
        if len(w) == 2 {
            bindKey, bindValue := w[0], w[1]
            if intV, err := strconv.ParseInt(bindValue, 10, 64); err == nil {
                // bind value is int
                field := fmt.Sprintf("`%s` > ?", bindKey)
                tx = tx.Where(field, intV)
            } else if fV, err := strconv.ParseFloat(bindValue, 64); err == nil {
                // bind value is float
                field := fmt.Sprintf("`%s` > ?", bindKey)
                tx = tx.Where(field, fV)
            } else if bindValue != "" {
                // bind value is string
                field := fmt.Sprintf("`%s` LIKE ?", bindKey)
                sV := fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", bindValue)
                tx = tx.Where(field, sV)
            }
        }
    }
    modelName := getType(m)
    rKey := redisPrefix + modelName + q.String() + "_count"
    v, err := mem.GetUint(rKey)
    if err != nil {
        var count uint
        tx.Count(&count)
        mem.Set(rKey, count)
        return count, tx
    }
    return v, tx
}

func getType(v interface{}) string {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        return "*" + t.Elem().Name()
    }
    return t.Name()
}
```

In my order model, I add

```
OrderDetail []OrderDetail `gorm:"foreignkey:OrderID" json:"detail_order"`
```

For my relation data. And the result is
[image]

Even though I have the relation data
[image]

My question, How I add / attach `OrderDetail struct` inside `Order struct` So that my table relationship data comes out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to add a `Preload` call into your query or a `Related` call after you've gotten your object.  See [the `Preload` docs here](http://gorm.io/docs/preload.html) or [the `Related` docs](http://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Working-with-Has-Many) for usage.  If you use `Preload`, which I'd recommend for simplicity, you might have to abandon your `crudOne` function or adapt it to work with your needs.

Comment: Yeah....Thanks @TimBrown for your help... I'm done with added `Preload("OrderDetail")`